# Using Spring Data Rest on Repository that uses Java 8 streams (for finders return type)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Changing my finders from

```
Collection<T> findByX(...)
```

to

```
Stream<T> findByX(...)
```

makes any call to         /entity/search/findByX?x=y fail with a PersistentEntity must not be null exception.

This is supported in Spring Data JPA but I have trouble finding if and how this is supported by Spring Data REST. Any clues?

This is using the dependencies coming from Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet supported. Digging into the source code spring date rest, look at the result transformation below. There is no way to handle Stream data.

AbstractRepositoryRestController.java

```
protected Object toResource(Object source, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler, Class<?> domainType,
        Link baseLink) {

    if (source instanceof Iterable) {
        return toResources((Iterable<?>) source, assembler, domainType, baseLink);
    } else if (source == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    } else if (ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(source.getClass())) {
        return source;
    }

    return assembler.toFullResource(source);
}
```